# MySQL multiple primary in one table and foreign key to another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am using myphpadmin

### tabel 1

```
                   id exam_name         month  year
                   ------------------------------------
                    1 universityexam   january  2013
```

here exam_name, month and year is primary key

### table 2

```
                   id exam_name                     course_name
                   ----------------------------------------------

                   1  universityexam january 2013     bsc
```

here exam_name is foreign key to all the column of the  table 1

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Why is he using phpmyadmin, that's the question.

Comment: there can't be multiple primary key in one table. U can go for unique and index values.

Comment: i need mysql query to multiple primary in table 1

Comment: as  Harjeet Jadeja said, you can't create more than 1 primary key in singe table

Comment: Document : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: @HarjeetJadeja You can however create one primary key with multiple columns.

Comment: @abbas What is the structure you want to achieve? Do you need to constrain table 1 to not have duplicates based on those two columns? That can be done either by using one primary key (composed of multiple columns) or one unique key (composed of multiple columns).

Comment: @abbas foreign keys must uniquely identify one single row. If you have a multiple column primary key your foreign key will have to be multiple column too.

Comment: Downvoted. The question is very unclear. Please add more detail.

Comment: @MihaiStancu :ya true, by mistake i was thinking about primary+auto-increment key, that can be only one. But primary key can be more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is but please forgive if your lack of detail has resulted in misunderstanding.

What you seem to want to be able to do is to link the two tables, but you are going about it the wrong way.  You should use the id from table1 as the FK in table2.  What you are doing is duplicating data unnecessarily.

It is possible to link one exam to many courses or one course to many exams in this way.

I would design the database thus:

```
create table courses (degree_id int,degree_name varchar(128))
create table exam (exam_id int,exam_name varchar(128))
create table exam_date(exam_date_id SERIAL,exam_id int,date timestamp)
create table exam_date_course(edc_id SERIAL,exam_date_id BIGINT,degree_id INT)
```

This allows you to link exams to dates, courses to exams etc very freely with little or no duplication of data (see 4th normal form on google)